# How to replace text in one file with text from another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to put text from a file in another file that also contains text. Example:

FILE 1 contains:

```
@WORLD
```

FILE 2 contains:

```
HELLO:LEARNING
```

I would like to insert the content of `FILE1` into `FILE2` to get:

```
HELLO@WORLD:LEARNING
```

More or less I have the code:

```
fname = input("Put your file: ")

if fname == "combos.txt":
    try:
        f = open(fname) #OPEN THE FILE "COMBOS.TXT"
        delimiter = ":"
        with open("combos.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8')as f: #WITH THE FILE "COMBOS.TXT" OPENED AS VARIABLE F
            data = [f"{x}{delimiter}{y}" for x,y in [tuple(i.strip().split(delimiter)) for i in f.readlines()]] #

            with open("lowercase - combos.txt", "w+", encoding='UTF-8')as f:
                f.write("\n".join(data))
                
            input("Your file was edited successfully! Press enter to continue...")
        
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            p = subprocess.call(["python", "start.py"])
    except:
        print("--Something went wrong while trying to load your file--")
```

The problem is in this part:

```
data = [f"{x}{delimiter}{y}" for x,y in [tuple(i.strip().split(delimiter)) for i in f.readlines()]] #
```

`x` and `y` are the text from FILE 2:
`HELLO`(X):`LEARNING` (Y)

And I would like to add the text from `FILE 1` --> `@WORLD` to FILE 2 in (X):

`HELLO@WORLD`(X):`LEARNING` (Y)

I don´t know how to fix it, I suppose that is editing variable `X`. I made different test (creating a variable to open the other file, or putting `write()` function. Not worked me, I don´t know if more or less is something like that but I couldn´t do it):

```
data = [f"{x}{delimiter}{y}"
```

Comment: What is the problem? *I made different test but I can´t do it* - doesn't tell us anything about what's wrong with your code... Please read [ask] and try to be more specific

Comment: Ups! Sorry I had not noticed

Comment: We would also need a clear [mre]

Comment: Edited =) Tomerikoo

Comment: Hi! I edited the post being more specific now in the problem. I wish that can help you =)

Comment: I don't understand what's the point of `data`... It's basically the original file. You're spliting each line on delimiter, and then string formatting it back together...

Comment: Yes, but is because I need to specify that the content of the file that script gonna edit, have to be mixed with the content from the other file. Example, convert the text from the file: HELLO:LEARNING into --> HELLO@WORLD:LEARNING. The text added have to comes from the other file (FILE2) that contains: @WORLD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create the new data to be in the format of:

```
{X from FILE2}{FILE 1}:{Y from FILE2}
```

Currently in your code I see that you only loop on a single file. You should loop on both files simultanasouly, using the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function. Then simply construct your data:

```py
with open(FILE1) as file1, open(FILE2) as file2:
    data = []
    for line1, line2 in zip(file1, file2):
        x, y = line2.split(':')
        data.append(f"{x}{line1.strip()}:{y}")

with open(FILE2, 'w') as file2:
    file2.writelines(data)
```

Note that you usually don't need to use `readlines()/read()` and create unnecessary lists/strings in memory for most file operations. You can just loop in-place directy on the lines of the file (`for line in file`) as files are iterators in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure of what you are wanting as the process of this program. I did come up with a result on my end matching your expectations. Validation is not provided, that is up to you.

```
# file1.txt = @WORLD
# file2.txt = HELLO:LEARNING
# file2.txt after run = HELLO@WORLD:LEARNING

def insert_file_in_file(f1_path, f2_path, placed_before = " "):
    with open(f1_path, "r") as f1:
        f1_text = f1.read()
    with open(f2_path, "r") as f2:
        f2_text = f2.read()

    with open(f2_path, "w") as f2:
        string_list = f2_text.split(placed_before)
        f2.write((f1_text + placed_before).join(string_list))

insert_file_in_file("file1.txt", "file2.txt", ":")
```